# What do the different coloured dots on microswitches mean?

Tags: switches, repair

What do the different coloured dots on microswitches mean? I see white, pink, blue, yellow "dots", the colour of the switch button itself, on a microswitch.

I'm looking for a Himake microswitch for my Logitech M185 mouse; will all "white dot" microswitches work - ie will they have the same height from the circuitboard-facing base to the top of the switch, the same travel, and the same (approx) resilience? Assuming I can interchange, is there a particular make that's known for longevity?

Comment: show datasheet.

Comment: I see this is closed - where can questions about electronic components be asked? Is there anywhere on the SE network that would accept a question like this? I thought an EE Q&A site would be perfect for this simple and succinct question on labelling of components ...?

Answer (score 1):

Claims from various sellers seem to indicate that the [D2FC-xxx](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/846832/Omron/D2FC-F-7N/1) switches are mostly physically interchangeable, but with subtle differences in contact alloy, lifetime, country of manufacture and feel, as indicated by the operator color.

Rated lifetime varies from 500x10^4 to 2000x10^4 (20 million) operations.

Edit: Mechanical drawing page from datasheet linked in above:

[image]

Chances are good Omron is the original manufacturer, and other similar switches from Taiwan etc. companies are copies.

Comment: @jsotola It works for me, but I'll edit in the drawing page

Comment: So there's no standard characteristic indicated by the colours, it's just manufacturer dependent? Do you know, for Omron say, any particular manufacturer variable dot colour indicates?

Comment: There might be an Omron document out there somewhere.

Comment: Dot colour may indicate operating force (spring strength) but really the way to know is to consult the datasheet for that range of switches.

Comment: @BrianDrummond That was my first thought (similar to mechanical keyboard switches) but it does not seem to be the story.